# Column name in pandas dataframe resulting from groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'clif_cod' : [1,2,3,3,4,4,4],
               'peds_val_fat' : [10.2, 15.2, 30.9, 14.8, 10.99, 39.9, 54.9],
               'mes' : [1,2,4,5,5,6,12],
               'ano' : [2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016]})

vetor_valores = df.groupby(['mes','clif_cod']).sum()
```

which yields me this output:

```
               ano         peds_val_fat
mes clif_cod                    
1   1         2016         10.20
2   2         2016         15.20
4   3         2016         30.90
5   3         2016         14.80
    4         2016         10.99
6   4         2016         39.90
12  4         2016         54.90
```

How do I select rows based on mes and clif_cod?

When I do list(df) I only get ano and peds_val_fat.

Comment: You have runnable code, so this is good. However, you have not made your problem lear. "Select row"... what rows? Based on what? Please provide some sample expected output based on your current input.

Comment: Thanks, but 1) Asking a question here isn't meant to help _just_ you. I asked you to _clarify_ your question so that it would become easier to understand what you asked for. I understood what you wanted but not everyone would at first glance. 2) I know what a "row" is, I have a pandas badge, and 3) I did not downvote, but I appreciate your jumping to conclusions anyway.

Comment: By the way, I will point out that almost every answer has made different assumptions based on your incomplete question (the missing link being _what_ should be selected based on which condition). The fact that not all answers give you the same thing mean your question was _not_ clear, so your argument is a _non-sequitur_.

Comment: Lastly, your title is not self-explanatory. You mention "column names" in the title, but you ask to select rows (again, I ask, based on what condition?). No one is hear to jump on you; if you'll read my first comment, I even complemented your efforts on creating a running example. I accept your apology, but in future I would advice you to be a little more receptive to feedback before lashing out. Good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can just pass the argument `as_index=False` to your groupby. You can then access it as you would any other dataframe

```
vetor_valores = df.groupby(['mes','clif_cod'], as_index=False).sum()

>>> vetor_valores
   mes  clif_cod   ano  peds_val_fat
0    1         1  2016         10.20
1    2         2  2016         15.20
2    4         3  2016         30.90
3    5         3  2016         14.80
4    5         4  2016         10.99
5    6         4  2016         39.90
6   12         4  2016         54.90
```

To access values, you can now use `iloc` or `loc` as you would any dataframe:

```
# Select first row:
vetor_valores.iloc[0]
...
```

Alternatively, if you've already created your groupby and don't want to go back and re-make it, you can reset the index, the result is identical.

```
vetor_valores.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `pd.IndexSlice`

```
vetor_valores.loc[[pd.IndexSlice[1,1]],:]
Out[272]: 
               ano  peds_val_fat
mes clif_cod                    
1   1         2016          10.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a dataframe with a two-level MultiIndex. Use both values to access rows, e.g., `vetor_valores.loc[(4,3)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `axis` parameter in `.loc`:

```
vetor_valores.loc(axis=0)[1,:]
```

Output:

```
               ano  peds_val_fat
mes clif_cod                    
1   1         2016          10.2
```